# Can I write Apps in Swift 1 (For iOS 7 and 8) using Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Can I write Apps in Swift 1 (For iOS 7 and 8) using Xcode 7? Or will compiled Swift 2 run on iOS 7-9?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to switch an XCode project to use Swift version 1.2 in the XCode 7 beta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951291/is-it-possible-to-switch-an-xcode-project-to-use-swift-version-1-2-in-the-xcode)

Comment: Xcode 7 only ships with the Swift 2.0 version of llvm, so no.

Comment: you can write for 8 but you'll have to wait until ios 9 comes out to upload it to the appstore (i found out the hard way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be errors if you attempt to run swift 1 in xcode 7, and yes, swift 2 will run on IOS 7-9

Answer (score 5):

No, you can not.

Each Version of Xcode includes only one version of the Swift Compiler. Using a newer Xcode Version will force you to adopt the new Swift Syntax.
There is an automatic converter available under `Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax`.

The iOS Version requirements are not affected by the use of Swift 2 (or Xcode 7). Apps built with Xcode 7 and written in Swift 2 can run on iOS 7 (same conditions/restrictions as before).